# History visualization tools for version control systems?

Tags: version-control, visualization, gource

Specifically, I'm looking for something that, given a single file, and an SVN history, will display insertions and deletions as a pretty animation.

That said: I figure that a list of version control visualizers might be a useful resource.

Comment: Did you ever find anything? This is exactly what I want. IE effectively a time-lapse view of the changes of a single file (I want to see how the dependencies change in a package.json)

Answer (score 27):

http://code.google.com/p/gource/ looks very pretty

Comment: gource doesn't seem to do what he's asking for... it displays high level changes to the network of files, not to one file.

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure about pretty, but **[codeswarm](http://code.google.com/p/codeswarm/)** is certainly one of the most impressive "commit history visualization" tool I have ever seen.

[image]
<sub>(source: [infovis-wiki.net](http://www.infovis-wiki.net/images/7/7f/Ogawa08codeswarm.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

In a more practical way, you may also consider **[SVN Time-Lapse View](http://code.google.com/p/svn-time-lapse-view/)**

> SVN Time-Lapse View is a cross-platform viewer that downloads all revisions of a file and lets you scroll through them by dragging a slider.
>   As you scroll, you are shown a visual diff of the current revision and the previous revision.
>   Thus you can see how a file evolved, and you can easily find the revision at which lines appeared, disappeared, or changed.

(not big on "animation", but still, can be useful)

[image: Annotated screenshot of the window]

Comment: It looks really good but is in java, which means I would have the java updater popping up every few days about getting the latest version java, so gonna give that oen a miss.

Comment: @danio: the java updater pops up only if you let it to. See for instance http://www.technipages.com/prevent-java-update-available-balloon-messages.html

Comment: thanks but I thought I had already tried to disable that. Will give it another go when I get back to my machine with Java installed.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the VCS have a web or GUI interface such as gitk, hgk and so on.  It shows the various "branches" and "merges" along the life of the repo but if you want something prettier then codeswarm is your answer :)